# Is "greeted to a place" ungrammatical?

Tags: grammar

The guests were greeted to our home.

Someone told me that the construction "greeted to a place" was ungrammatical, but that's weird, because I have seen it in a number of places. Is this the case? Why is it ungrammatical? I thought greeted to was similar to welcomed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 similar concepts: *introduce*, *greet*, and *welcome*.

Use **Introduce** for the *first time* meeting or experience.

> Ms. Frisby introduced her guests to the old man.
>
> Karl introduced Bob to jazz music.

Use **Greet** for the act or gesture of *saying hello*.

> Ms. Frisby greeted her guests with a wave from the balcony.
>
> A small dog greeted them with his wagging tail.

Use **Welcome** to show friendship and generosity.

> **The guests were welcomed into our home.**
>
> Ms. Frisby left clean towels in the spare bedroom to welcome her guests.

I think the word you want is "welcomed".

Comment: I found some sentences: Crabtree went to visit the cyclewear company, which is located in Shepley, and greeted them to the Giants Business Club; He was also impressed by how friendly and welcoming the staff were, especially the Lofthouse family who personally greeted them to the site. What do you think?

Comment: @JJJJ, in that sentence I would use "*introduced* them to the Giants Business Club". They all have overlapping meaning, and there may be regional differences.

Comment: So it could be considered correct?

Comment: @JJJJ In that sentence "Giants Business Club" is a group of people, not a place. As a native speaker, I would **never** say *"The guests were greeted to our home."* You cannot be greeted to inanimate objects. You don't "wave hello" to a house or a car (without poetic license: "the friendly flowers greeted the guests with cheerful colors…").

Comment: @JJJJ Source for those examples? They sound totally wrong to me, but as wetcircuit says, there may be regional differences.